# Should client side have a log?

Tags: logging, vb.net

The client side of my application is written in VB.Net, it accesses a java server. 
Server logs every request that was made by client, client shows every exception to the user (with an option to send it to support).

The question is: would you add logs to the client side?
If yes, what information does it make sense to write to the client log?

Comment: Maybe? This is a lot more complicated question than "would you add logs to client side?" and really not answerable without a lot more information...

Comment: It can't hurt. Working out how to get the logs back to your server is a nuisance, but logging ought to be of some use in any fallible or non-trivial software.

Comment: client side logs can be very helpful in diagnosing connection failures

Comment: "client shows every exception to the user (with an option to send it to support)". Really?!?? Forget client logs; fix this usability/maintenance farce first: have the server send the exception to support, always. Tell the user something went wrong, but that support have been told.

Comment: Only give users information about the errors/situations they may solve themselves ("your password is wrong", "You are not allowed to perform that operation"). "Connection is lost" is somewhat borderline, depending of which side has the issue. For all of the others, "Internal error" and send the log to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have integrated with a team that used a pure desktop application with the server meaning the "database" - for them it made complete sense to have a client side log because that is where all the code was executed. There was no other way to debug an issue if it ever occurred. In terms of "what" to log - it is subjective and based pure on what you will need for debuging? This is never easy to answer even if you were logging on the server.

But these are the considerations I would keep in mind since you are NOT on a server,

- You have no way to "protect" the logs from an unauthorized edit, at least not the level of confidece you could have in a server.
- You need to be extra careful about logging sensitive information as it could be misused.
- Disk space on the client side is not in your control - so make sure you don't exhaust an already overly crowded hard disk of your user.
- Make sure you have a reasonable rolling scheme for the logs of some way to archive them.
- Also will the developers be able to access these logs? How? Will users "email" the logs? If so make sure they are a reasonable size that can be emailed.

Answer (score 0):

Every code which is complicated enough that it won't be straigtforward to debug should create logs. The fact that it's running on client side is irrelevant.

You can skip logging if:

- You are not expecting to support the application, that is you are developing a prototype or abandonware.
- The logic is extremely simple and consists of 1:1 mapping of server calls. Aside theoretical examples good for tutorials, I can't imagine any concrete example of an app which does something useful while being in this case.
- You're paid per hour of support and your company has no respect towards their customers. Longer debugging means more money, short term. Absence of logs means more debugging time.